# Beamer: fade and zoom in \xymatrix environment

Tags: beamer, zooming

I am preparing a presentation in Beamer. I have the following diagram

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centerline{
\xymatrix{
 & *+[F-,]{\txt{Text 1}}\ar[dl]\ar[dr]  \\
*+[F-,]{\txt{Text 2}} &  & *+[F-,]{\txt{Text 3}}
}
}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

I would like to zoom in to "Text 2" while fading everything else. Then I want to reverse the procedure: zoom out and restoring the entire diagram. Is this possible?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Do you think you could settle fot a _TikZ_ solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can have different zoom behavior here is one option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=zooms]
\framezoom<1><2>(2.5cm,1.5cm)(2cm,1.5cm)

\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\xymatrix{
 & *+[F-,]{\txt{Text 1}}\ar[dl]\ar[dr]  \\
*+[F-,]{\txt{Text 2}} &  & *+[F-,]{\txt{Text 3}}
}
}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2->[plain]{zooms}
\againframe<1>[plain]{zooms}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please see the manual for other options.